# Construction of JSON types in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell, types

I have been toying around with the JSON module for Haskell, and I wanted to manually create some JSON, close to this:

```
{
  "data": { "unit": "cm" },
  "name": "Hodor"
}
```

So I tried something like this:

```
toJSObject [ 
  ("data", toJSObject [ ("unit", toJSString "cm") ]), 
  ("name", toJSString "Hodor")
]
```

However, I kept getting type mismatches because the `data` field is of type `JSObject JSString`, while the `name` field is of type `JSString`. Why is it not able to infer the general type `JSValue` -- both `JSObject` and `JSString` should be a subtype. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haskell does not have subtype polymorphism: the whole mechanism you're basing your intuition off of here is nonexistent. You cannot make heterogenous lists at all. Instead you need to convert all of the elements of your list to the same sum type like `Either`.

Comment: Oh, I see. So one would be forced to write JSObject (Either A B)? Would you mind giving a brief example in an answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JSON` but there ought to be a more specific sum type to JSON itself which you should use. I'd answer, but I'd want to do that research first.

Comment: Note that including the actual type error helps getting good answers.

Comment: See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections for ways of coping with heterogeneous lists. J. Abrahamson's suggestion is the first one discussed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As J. Abrahamson pointed out there is no subtype polymorphism in Haskell so you can't represent a list of *distinct* types. The JSON `Value` sum type provided by Aeson library ( the de-facto JSON library) can be used for constructing a JSON "heterogeneous" JSON where all values are wrapped up the uniform `Value` type.

```
type Object = HashMap Text Value

type Array = Vector Value

-- | A JSON value represented as a Haskell value.
data Value = Object !Object
           | Array !Array
           | String !Text
           | Number !Scientific
           | Bool !Bool
           | Null
```

Using this we create a type `M.HashMap Text Value` and wrap it in an Object.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M

example :: Value
example = Object $ M.fromList [
    ("data", Object $ M.fromList [ ("unit", "cm") ]),
    ("name", "Hodor")
  ]

main = print $ encode example
```

Which gives you the lazy bytestring:  `{"data":{"unit":"cm"},"name":"Hodor"}`

Comment: Perfect. I thought that was what the ``JSValue`` type did in the other library. But this was just what I was looking for, thanks.